# .swift file name containing plus sign

Tags: swift

I opened an XCode project produced as a tutorial by Apple ("Auto Layout Cookbook"), when I found two files with a strange naming:

1. *Recipe+Loading.swift*
2. *Recipe+Storyboards.swift*

Both contain an extension called Recipe. I was not able to find any docs about this kind of naming.

Is there any reason why they named the files this way?

Comment: This is just a convention for naming categories from the ObjC era ("_A category is usually declared in a separate header file and implemented in a separate source code file. In the case of XYZPerson, you might declare the category in a header file called XYZPerson+XYZPersonNameDisplayAdditions.h._") https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html

Comment: @Alladinian: thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The naming comes from Objective-C where every extension for a class needed a name. For example, a class `Recipe` could have extension:

```
@interface Recipe (Loading)
@end
```

which contained methods related to "Loading".
Such extensions were commonly put into files named `Recipe+Loading.h` (that is, class `Recipe` extended with `Loading` methods).

In Swift extensions don't have a name but old habits die hard. They used the same naming for files.

Comment: Could it be a way to avoid naming collisions too? In this project in the same directory there is a Recipe.swift containing a Recipe struct, for example

Comment: @IanBell If you mean collisions in file names, then yes. It's a way to split the implementation into multiple files.

Comment: Anyone know if this naming convention changes how swift handles local imports?

Answer (score 0):

This is a common naming convention from Objective-C.  As you surmised it basically contains extensions to `Recipe` that pertain to  loading and storyboards respectively.  It's primarily a way to break up large source files or label extensions to system classes (String, Array, etc.)